# How to distinguish variable from literal/constant in function parameters

Tags: perl

In such case, how to recognize whether there were variable or literal was passed to the function f()?

How to implement passed_as_constant() check (see in the code below)?

```
sub f {
  my $refStr=\$_[0];
  return if passed_as_constant($_[0]) and !defined(wantarray);
  substr(${$refStr}, 0, 1)='D';
# return the copy of the string if it was passed
# to the function as constant aka "literally" or if copying was explicitly requested by the left-side context
  (passed_as_constant($_[0]) or defined(wantarray)) and return ${$refStr};
}
# Argument was passed literally and function called without left-side context - we may simply "do nothing"
f('Bingo!');

# Argument was passed literally and left-side context is here. We must return a copy of literal/constant
say my $s=f('Bingo!');

# Here we can modify the $s "in-place"
f(my $s='Bingo!');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do this. The function should always behave the same. In-place modifications are rather non-obvious. If you want to modify a value, explicitly ask for a reference. This makes the modification more visible at the call site.

If you really have to determine whether an argument is constant, you can use [`readonly()` from Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#readonly). Internally, each scalar has a flag that controls whether modifications are allowed. This is set for literals. Assignments to read-only scalars will fail. With `readonly()` you can query this flag.

Comment: Seconding the "don't do this" advice.

Comment: Thank you very much, amon! Scalar::Util::readonly It's exactly what i need.

Comment: except that the answer tries to explain why you *don't* need that and *shoudn't* need that :(